# Function with multiple columns to get one output

Tags: r, function

I want to write a function that will classify each row based on the values within three columns as either poor, medium or good

Here is example data

```
C = c(1, 0.4, 3, 6, 2)
N = c(0.1, 3, 5, 7, 13)
P = c(2, 3, 3, 4, 2)

mydf = data.frame(C,N,P)
```

Lets say I want to classify all things with C < 0.5 as poor, regardless of N or P. Likewise for all values of N > 10

Any values with C such that 1 < C < 4, and P such that 1 < P < 4 are classified as good

Everything else is classified as medium

Currently I have used a several if functions that checks for each condition at a time and then a final function to see if all required conditions are good then the final classification is good, if there any that are poor then its poor, otherwise medium.

Instead I would like a way to do it all in one function because I have to expand it to many more conditions (20+). I have tried using the ifelse function but I couldn't really figure it out

If there are any good sources to read about such functions I appreciate any input, thanks

Comment: First thing to do: figure out *why* you think you need to apply twenty separate(independent) boundaries to your data. I'm a bit skeptical that you can have that many hard limits, as opposed to statistical probability tails. Next, see if you can't come up with a formula (equation) that takes `C,N,P,...` as inputs and whose output indicates the "good/mid/poor" state.  Possibilities include clustering and weighted sums or products.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
> mydf$result = with(mydf, ifelse(C<0.5 | N>10, 'poor',ifelse(C<4 & C>1 & P>1 & P<4, 'good', 'medium')))
> 
> mydf
    C    N P result
1 1.0  0.1 2 medium
2 0.4  3.0 3   poor
3 3.0  5.0 3   good
4 6.0  7.0 4 medium
5 2.0 13.0 2   poor
```

To create a function:

```
myfn = function(ddf){
    ddf$res = with(ddf, ifelse(C<0.5 | N>10, 'poor',ifelse(C<4 & C>1 & P>1 & P<4, 'good', 'medium')))
    ddf
}
```

To write ifelse repeatedly:

```
ddf$res = with(ddf, ifelse(C<0.5 | N>10, 'poor',
                    ifelse(C<4 & C>1 & P>1 & P<4, 'good', 
                        'medium'
                    ))  # number of these closing brackets should be same as number of 'ifelse'
                    )  # this closing bracket is for 'with' function
```

Comment: Note to the OP: since you mention that you have 20+ conditions, just be aware that nesting 20+ `ifelse`s into each other may end up in a not very efficient computation. Unfortunately, I can't tell you a much better alternative right now.. If you have only very few levels of nesting, like in @rnso's answer, it should be fine and efficient.

Comment: I'd be tempted to run a sequence of subsetting ops, e.g. `medgood<-mydata[mydata$C >0.5]` , then` good<-medgood[min(medgood[,c('C','P']>=1 & max(medgood[,c('C','P']<=4),]` and so on. This is clunkier but has the advantage of saving subsets for future analysis.